# Failed to initialize App Engine SDK 1.8.9

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using Indigo on a Mac Pro (10.9.1). I updated to Java1.7 in order to run some updated Google Play Service samples. Under Installed JREs, JAVA7 is shown as the only and default choice, which points to the new Java path. But when I start Eclipse, it started complaining that "JRE version is 1.6.0; version 1.7.0 or later is needed to run Google plugin for Eclipse".

I tried to add the vm option in eclipse.ini, i.e. I added 
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/home/bin/java
above "-vmargs" as described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini.

It doesn't make any difference though. Since then, I have uninstalled GPE from Eclipse and installed them again via "install new software" from https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7. Still the same problem. Under Google->App Engine, there is an error message "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK (path)". This points to appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9.

I have checked my Java version using all means I am aware of, i.e. from run Java -version, using Java's control panel, output from code... They all show I am using Java 1.7.0.51.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Google has provided a solution that works great. Add this argument in eclipse.ini
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_WHATEVERTHESUFFIXIS/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that eclipse Is compiling your project to 1.7 specifications. Even though you have 1.7 selected as your virtual machine, it might be compiling to 1.6. It's in the eclipse project settings

Comment: I can't find any setting that still refers to anything other than 1.7. But I don't think this issue is project related anyway, as I get this message even when there is no project in the workspace.